# Using a static method in C++ to implement a factory pattern

Tags: c++, design-patterns, factory, factory-pattern

I am a relatively new C++ programmer.
In writing some code I've created something similar in concept to the code below. When a friend pointed out this is in fact a factory pattern I read about the pattern and saw it is in similar.

In all of the examples I've found the factory pattern is always implemented using a separate class such as `class BaseFactory{...};` and not as I've implemented it using a static `create()` member function.

My questions are:
(1) Is this in fact a factory pattern?
(2) The code seems to work. Is there something incorrect in the way I've implemented it?
(3) If my implementation is correct, what are the pros/cons of implementing the static `create()` function as opposed to the separate `BaseFactory` class.

Thanks!

```
class Base {
    ...
    virtual ~Base() {}
    static Base* create(bool type);
}

class Derived0 : public Base {
    ...
};

class Derived1 : public Base {
    ...
};

Base* Base::create(bool type) {
    if(type == 0) {
        return new Derived0();
    }
    else {
        return new Derived1();
    }
}

void foo(bool type) {
    Base* pBase = Base::create(type);
    pBase->doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Not easily extensible, if I wanted to add a new derived type I'd have to modify the original factory instead of just creating a new factory class. If the factory lives in a third-party library out of my control then it's simply impossible to do it. Hence the usual design based on inheritance.

Comment: @syam that is abstract factory, not factory

Comment: @BЈовић Ah right. I guess I never use the "plain" factory pattern hence my confusion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a typical way to implement the factory pattern, the main reason being that the factory class isn't typically a base of the classes it creates. A common guideline for when to use inheritance is "Make sure public inheritance models "is-a"". In your case this means that objects of type `Derived0` or `Derived1` should also be of type `Base`, and the derived classes should represent a more specialised concept than the Base.

However, the factory pattern pretty much always involves inheritance as the factory will return a pointer to a base type (yous does this too). This means the client code doesn't need to know what type of object the factory created, only that it matches the base class's interface.

With regard to having a static create functions, it depends on the situation. One advantage, as your example shows, is that you won't need to create an instance of the factory in order to use it.

Comment: take a note that his "factory" returns a pointer to the base class

Answer (score 1):

Your factory is ok, except for the fact that you merged the factory and the interface, breaking the [SRP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) principle.

Instead of making the create static method in the base class, create it in another (factory) class.